# Java based mailer not displaying properly in gmail

Tags: css, html-email, mailer

I have made a java mailer which is not displaying properly in [gmail](http://gmail.com), but it is showing up properly in hotmail. In gmail, the CSS is not getting read properly, which disturbs the entire layout.

Comment: so what is your problem?

Comment: welcome to the joys of E-Mail Styling (all mail clients seem to mash it up in different ways)

Comment: It does not have anything to do with Java or Java Mail API. I am removing those tags.

Comment: same i have made it with PHP mailer but does not have issues on any browser, but with java mailer it has

Comment: oh, is it? may be you need to show some code then.

Answer (score 0):

Follow a couple of rules:

1. If possible, just design everything in a table. Keep `fixed` layout.
2. Don't use CSS file reference. Just do styling in the elements.
3. Try avoiding images or at least keep as minimal as company's logo only.
4. Keep limited number of links in E-mails. This point is to avoid your automated mails to go in junk folder.
5. Avoid complex CSS rules.

---

**Updated**

By the way, you **must** set content type `"text/html"`. You may look couple of good already done examples:

- Real's How to: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0504.html
- Another detailed and good worked out example: http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/javamail.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: css is implemented in the HTML page itself as internal css

Comment: @Ruheet can't say what went wrong with your code until you explain more. I have added some Java specific details that might be missing on rendering side.

Comment: is it googd to give the css internally or inline?

Comment: I have played with a couple of HTML mails. I never get burnt using Table and and inline. I personally feel internal CSS may be tricky, there are already mail provider's CSS, and attempts to avoid scripts and what not. So, I fall-back to inline. But, people may not agree with that.

Comment: does making it div based affects the thing

Comment: @Ruheet nope. It does not affect things. I just avoid `float`s and other relative positioning things.